# Stop NSWindow from receiving input events temporarily

Tags: macos

I want to prevent an NSWindow from receiving (or handling) inputs events temporarily. As if a sheet is displayed or the run loop is busy executing code. How can I do that?

Why?

Currently when the user executes a 'command' in my application it's handled on the main thread. This of course causes the window to become unresponsive for the duration of the command. This is fine most of the time as the commands normally take 1 - 2 seconds to execute.

Sometimes though the command can take a very long time (60 seconds or more). To give the user an option to cancel the command I want to execute it in the background and if the command does not finish in about 2 seconds I want to put up a sheet with some information and a cancel button.

I don't want to put up the sheet immediately, as that would cause very annoying appear/disappear animations most of the time, but I need to block the GUI for those first 2 seconds.

Comment: You say 'I want to execute it in the background', but you also want to 'block the GUI for those first 2 seconds'. This seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: After the first two seconds I want to put up a sheet with a cancel button. I need the main run loop for that, so the command needs to execute in the background. The sheet will then take care of blocking the main window.

Comment: If the GUI is blocked for the first 2 seconds, why don't you just display the sheet straight away with the cancel button disabled? Enable the button once 2 seconds are up, and, as a bonus, there will be no beach-balling.

Comment: Because most of the time the command runs very short and I want to prevent a lot of half appearing and directly disappearing sheets.

Comment: Why do you need to block the UI, then?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee that the user doesn’t enter a second command or other operation before the first command is finished. I just want to make sure my model remains steady during execution of the command until I decide to put up the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding `sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent)` in your NSWindow subclass. Use a flag to let the window know that it should not handle events temporarily:

```
override func sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent) {
    guard shouldSendEvents else { return }
    super.sendEvent(event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this UI design is good, but if you must… you can use a semaphore. Initialize it with a count of 0. The background thread will signal it when it completes. The main thread can, after spawning the background task, wait on it with a timeout of 2 seconds. If the background task finishes first, the main thread will resume at that time. If the timeout expires, the main thread will resume and can show the sheet with the Cancel button.

By the way, if the background task takes *just* over 2 seconds, you will still show a sheet and then immediately dismiss it.

Comment: I realise that the sheet is sometimes still shown very short, but only in 0.1% of the cases, instead of 98%. I think this is acceptable.

Comment: As for the GUI design, I'm open for suggestions :)